# Is docker storage driver overlay2 production available on CentOS 7.5?

Tags: docker

When I read the docker document about the overlay2 storage driver on CentOS, I didn't see **whether it was clearly production available**(as https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-storage-drivers-per-linux-distribution show, the recommended storage driver on centos not contains overlay2, but when i yum install docker 1.13.1 on centos, defalut storage driver is overlay2). So i want to confirm whether it was already production on CentOS, thank you very much for your answer.

ps: my CentOS version is 7.5.1804 (3.10.0-862.e17.x86_64) and defalut use overlay2.

Answer (score 0):

The overlay2 driver is supported for Docker EE 17.06.02-ee5 and later and recommended for Docker CE.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites

Comment: Thank for your anwser, I'm a new dockerer, dest it means overlay2 driver is production available on CentOS when i ues docker 1.13.1? or use docker CE, like 17.xx?

Comment: You need to use docker-ce 17.xx and higher. Do not use old docker ce version.
docker-ce is community edition. docker-ee enterprise edition.

Comment: Oh, is there some problems with the docker 1.13.1 version provided by default? Just like? Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: docker 1.13.1 may not particularly have issues, but it doesn't support the latest features. We recently had to upgrade from it to docker-ce 17+ to support multi-stage container builds (we jumped to 20.* though).